# Error to Integrating SquishIt with Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, squishit

i'm trying to use SquishIt in my Asp.net pages, but i'm receiving this error bellow

[image]

My code : <%@ Import Namespace="SquishIt.Framework" %>

Web config : debug false

Comment: Are you using VB or C#?  The code looks like C#, but the error implies that the compiler thinks it should be VB.  If you're using VB, a carriage return is a meaningful part of the language.  These lines of code would need to be on the same line, or separated with a `_` maybe?

Comment: ok now is working , it's good , one last doubt: i can add all my css files? it's a good pratice?

Comment: Well, you can add any CSS files you want.  It's not good practice to send anything to the client that the client won't need, since that's just wasted resources.  But if there's no noticeable difference then you can always defer that cleanup to a later time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with whatever SquishIt is.

In VB a carriage return is part of the syntax.  (Unlike C# which treats a carriage return as meaningless whitespace.)  So this code is invalid:

```
Bundle.Css()
  .Add("something")
  ' and so on
```

In VB you'd either need to have it on one line:

```
Bundle.Css().Add("something") ' and so on
```

or explicitly separate the lines:

```
Bundle.Css() _
  .Add("something") _
  ' and so on
```